# Trouble with BoxFit while trying to fit an Image to a Stack

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently facing a problem with trying to fit an Image asset into a Stack widget in Flutter. I am using the `BoxFit.cover` property to make the image fit the Stack's dimensions, but unfortunately, it's not working as expected.

Here's the code snippet that I'm working with:

```dart
Stack(
    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter,
    children: [
      Image.asset(
        onboardingContents[index].image,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => controller.nextPage(
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              curve: Curves.easeIn),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50), color: Colors.white),
            height: sizeV * 6,
            width: sizeH * 60,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text(
                'Next',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

first thing your image is behind the container, to bring it to front you should write it below your container,then in order to make image fit the container, you should  use positioned.fill()

```
Stack(
    children:[
    //container(),
    Positioned.fill(child:Image()),
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `alignment` in your Stack. That means an Image should be aligned to bottom center if it's smaller than a screen. Remove `alignment`. If you need to align your container, do it separately.